# Setting up a REST API with CORS on Eclipse Tomcat 6

Tags: javascript, tomcat, server, cors

What I'm trying to do:

```
I want to set up a server that processes GET requests and can be called from any domain.
None of the data is private so I want to enable CORS.
```

Why?

```
I'm trying to teach people web development one step at a time.
Step 1 I want to teach people basic javascript and pulling data without them
needing to interact with the server side at all.
```

Current infrastructure:

```
I'm running a tomcat server in eclipse, with a few get requests coded in java.
I want users to be able to make get requests from their localhosts or 
from any url just by typing in the chrome console. I currently can execute the
get requests from the same domain, but when I try from my localhost I get an error.
```

What I've tried so far:

```
oh boy where to start:
1. upgrading tomcat, possible but would need to go through lots of bureaucracy
2. Updating the web.xml with a CORS filter. 
   Every time I do this it ends up failing to start the server
3. jsonp. This works to get the data looking in the network tab, but my success
   function isn't being called, and research shows it's because I'm passing
   a json object and the browser is expecting a jsonp. How can I do that from the
   server?
4. Setting crossOrigin: true in the ajax request. That doesn't work and I still
   get the same "no Access-control-allow-origin header is present..." error.
```

Any suggestions on other things to try or maybe details on why none of the things I've tried have worked?

Thanks.

Comment: ugh I thought I was being clever using the code to indent and make it look better, but the highlighting is bad :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, all you need for the scenario you described to work would be the "Access-control-allow-origin" header, as the error tries to tell you. None of the steps you tried so far seemed to have gone into that direction (despite the CORS filter perhaps).

There are certainly more elegant ways to add CORS headers, but I think you could get away by adding the header in your servlet:

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
}
```

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but what is the servlet? For reference this is how my requests are set up now:

@RequestMapping(value = "/blah",method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
[java method]

Is that the servlet? I added the doGet function to this same class and that did nothing, is there something in one of the tomcat config files I need to change? Thanks.

Comment: No such thing as dumb questions :-) Maybe you could show me how you generate the response in Java since this is the point where you would need to set the header - not the request.

Comment: Ah, spring. Take a look at this: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html 

Seems like adding @CrossOrigin might be what you are looking for.

Comment: CrossOrigin looks like exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately when I enter @CrossOrigin, I get the error "CrossOrigin cannot be resolved to a type" and although the server will still run, I still get the CORS error when trying to issue that GET request. For the other solutions, I'm not sure where I should define the class that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter such that the tomcat server will add that back into the response header.

Comment: You do have added the import?

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin

Comment: I tried adding the mvc:cors tags to the [project name]-servlet.xml file, and got:
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException...The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element "mvc:cors"

Comment: And you would need spring version >= 4.2 it seems.

Comment: what import are you discussing?

Comment: So @CrossOrigin would go where RequestMapping annotation is and would need an import near the top of your file that looks like 'import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin'

Comment: ugh there are several similar import statements, but when I try to add that one it says the import cannot be resolved. I'm looking at a lot of the jar files and it appears I have version 4.0.5 which would explain why this isn't working. Any idea if there's a way to implement it myself or should I look into upgrading? As you may be able to tell I'm a bit in over my head on all this spring/tomcat stuff. I understand the basics of what the issue is and if I could directly modify the response headers probably wouldn't have an issue, I'm just not sure how to do that through the current setup here.

Comment: Yea, the version explains that the import is not being resolved. I don't think you could *easily* implement it yourself, so I'd suggest updating spring. However, as I am doing some teaching in this domain myself, you might ask yourself if Tomcat + Spring is really something that you need on that level or if it adds more complexity than necessary. You could take a look at Jetty for example to get low-level access to the request and response. Upgrading spring is probably faster, though.

Comment: ah ok I'll check out Jetty. And yeah this is all from a configuration someone else set up that no one else could figure out and since I knew java was tasked with the job of figuring it out. If I could find a much lighter-weight solution that focuses strictly on handling http requests I'd much rather figure that out because it will be easier to maintain in the future as well. Thanks for all the help :)